# How can I draw a circle directly on a game window using python

Tags: python

I am programming a fortnite cheat with a basic softaim which is what the circle I am trying to make is for
I am trying to draw the fov circle with a python script. I have a script for the aimbot but I dont have anything else like a customizable fov circle or even a login for the menu

```
# This is one of the methods I tried
from turtle import *

turtle = getturtle()


root = (turtle
    ._screen
    .getcanvas()
    .winfo_toplevel())
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)

turtle.width(10)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)
```

I tried to create a window with a circle on it but it would not allow the user to input things in the game
EDITED

```py
# This is the other way I tried
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import win32gui
import win32con

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the window dimensions
window_width = 800
window_height = 600

# Set up the window as an overlay
window_flags = pygame.NOFRAME | pygame.SWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF
window_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), flags=window_flags)
pygame.display.set_caption('Transparent Overlay')

# Set up colors
TRANSPARENT = (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Fully transparent

# Set up the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Make the window always on top (Windows specific code)
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)

# Main game loop
while True:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Clear the window with a transparent color
    window_surface.fill(TRANSPARENT)

    # Get the current window dimensions
    window_rect = window_surface.get_rect()

    # Calculate the radius of the circle based on the fov variable
    fov = 50  # You can change this variable to adjust the radius dynamically
    radius = min(window_rect.width, window_rect.height) * fov / 100

    # Calculate the center point of the circle
    center = (window_rect.centerx, window_rect.centery)

    # Draw the hollow circle
    pygame.draw.circle(window_surface, pygame.Color('red'), center, int(radius), 1)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```